# Why is this algorithm using the bitwise and operator in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm

I see an algorithm such as:

```
    for (int i = 1; i < sums.length; i++) {
        /*
         * dynamic programming:
         * 1. remove a single block from the current subset of blocks
         * 2. the corresponding block sum was already calculated
         * 3. add the number on the removed block to it
         *
         * here: always choose the block corresponding
         * to the least significant bit of i
         */
        int t = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(i & -i);
        sums[i] = sums[i & ~(1 << t)] + block[t];

        //only add block subsets that add up to a face
        if (masks.containsKey(sums[i]))
            masks.get(sums[i]).add(i);
    }
```

According to the comments, in this line (*int t = Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(i & -i);*) the author means to choose an element in the block array according to the least significant bit of the number i.

Why is the author using a bitwise and operator on i and -i?  Couldn't they just use i (e.g., *Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros(i)*)?

Here is the larger body of code for context: http://pastebin.com/YB9wsdgD

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, you can do that. Few plausible explanations:

- The original version ported to something that had a home brew version and he left that trick in there.
- Didn't understand that Integer.numberOfTrailingZeros() doesn't care if there are other significant bits and knew how to quickly get a value of just the most significant bit.
- Or there was originally a home brew version that just got used i & -i and bitshifted until the value was zero and set that equal to t. And somebody just replaced that operation with the built-in without realizing i & -i was a trick that made that work the deleted operation work. Checking against zero is faster than other checks though it doesn't matter much anymore, so some hyper optimizing people would very often arrange things to check against zero, especially if they didn't have to subtract.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  document.write(i & -i);
  document.write('<br>');
}
```

The i & -i returns the binary representation of the 2s complement which is to say flipping all the bits and adding one. As such it will end up with just the binary amount of the carry. You can then determine how many zeros are after the 1 in the binary representation there. Generally by bitshifting until you find the 1, and the number of bitshifts is how many zeros that number had in the least significant place. This can be used to bitshift until you have a zero. Though Integer's version of that code doesn't need that.

Comment: I was just trying to show what i & -i looks like. It's not intended to be helpful in any other manner. I don't think there's java code with a "Run code snippet" button built into the webpage.

Comment: but change var to int, and document.write() to System.println() and remove the bit about <br>

Comment: The script appears in place. And doesn't depend on external links. And properly shows what i & -i does as i increases. If I thought it was contentious I wouldn't have bothered. The point is it preserves the least significant 1 and nothing else, which is useful if you're checking against zero, or think the algorithm would need that, but not for much else given the purpose there. But, a single bitwise and is basically free so meh.